# Sorting ember-data live array in route model hooks

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

in a ember route's model hook the following works fine:

```
model: function () {
    return this.modelFor('foo').get('bar');
}
```

Backed by ember-data, I can delete some of foo's bars somewhere else and it will be updated automagically (live array).

Now, I want this to be sorted (and user in sub-routes, so I have to do this in the route, not in the controller).

```
model: function () {
    return this.modelFor('foo').get('bar')
       .then(function (data) {
        return data.sortBy('baz');
    });
},
```

... does the job only the first time around, because I'm losing the updating.

Is there a way to write automatic updating sorting in line? What is the ember way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question, based on the answer from Gaurav:

```
 model: function () {
    return this.modelFor('foo').get('bar')
        .then(function (data) {
            return Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({
                arrangedContent: Ember.computed.sort('content', 'props'),
                props: ['baz:asc']
            }).create({
                content: data});
        });
},
```

Comment: Thank you, works here. Is there a shorter way of doing it? Seems like a lot of boilerplate for Ember. I'd expect something like `this.store.find('post').sortBy(['baz:asc'])`

Comment: The `find` returns a promise, so you'd have to wait for that with a `.then(...)`. Now you're quite near to the code shown in my question that works only the first time around. I'm not aware of a replacement for `sortBy` that would return a live array. Obviously, you could implement that yourself. So far I needed this construct in only two places, so I didn't go that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an Ember Object for your model that has a computed property that is the sorted data.

```
model: function () {
    return this.modelFor('foo').get('bar')
       .then(function (data) {
            return Ember.Object.extend({
                arrangedData: Ember.computed.sort('model', 'props'),
                props: ['baz:asc']
            }).create({ model: data });
       });
},
```

The Ember.Object.extend part should probably be extracted somewhere so it can be reused in other routes.

Comment: Thanks, this made me think in the right direction. 

The props have to be an array for this to work. 

Additionally, with this I'd have to write `{{model.arrangedData.baz}}` in a template. 

I've extended this by using an ArrayProxy and added my own answer.